# Is it possible to use survey list to create a quiz application?

Tags: survey-list

Is it possible to use survey list for quiz application, which maintains the scores for individual users.

Comment: Please don't add your name or "Thanks" as a signature to posts as this doesn't provide valuable information. Your user name is already displayed on the post, and the best way to show thanks is by upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of times a person can fill in the survey to one, and you can hide the responses from other users, but, since it is a survey, you can not (out of the box) mark which answer is correct and count the number of correct answers for an user.

You can however manually compare the answers given by a user with the correct answers. For a small amount of people this can be do-able. (What is more work? Do the checking yourself or code a solution).